# Access nested properties in angular2 template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Having a issue accessing a nested object in my angular2 template. The error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in /app/admin/property/items/property-items.html:7:52 caused by: self.context.property.PropertyDataType is undefined

My Template code:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 content-area" *ngIf="property.PropertyDataType.IsList == true">
    </div>
```

But when I console.log(object) in my component I have access to all properties. See screenshot:

[image]

I wouldof thought that I can just access the nested properties via "property.PropertyDataType.IsList" in my template but it does not seem to recognize the nested property: PropertyDataType.

Any help would be grateful. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the safe-navigation operator to preven errors in case the value is not yet set when Angular resolves the binding:

```
*ngIf="property?.PropertyDataType?.IsList == true"
```

Comment: Ah I forgot about this!. Thanx